# Max value of integer from nested irregular list (distinct sublists length and object types) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the list:

```
    assigned = [['A',[4, 5, 6]],['B',[7, 8, 9]],['D',[2,3]],['C',[14]]]
```

I wish to retry the maximum value for an integer inside the sublists.
In the presented case it would be 14.

My first step was to flat the list:

```
    def flattenToMax(x):

        if isinstance(x,list):
            return [a for i in x for a in flattenToMax(i)]
        else:
            return [x]
```

The result is:

```
    ['A', 4, 5, 6, 'B', 7, 8, 9, 'D', 2, 3, 'C', 14]
```

Then I've made:

```
    maxNum = (max([x for x in toMax if isinstance(x,int)]))
```

And the output is my expected result 14.
I ask, how can I combine the two steps into a single function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways you could do this. From what I get your issue is that you cannot add this part to your function because it is a recursive function:

```
maxNum = (max([x for x in toMax if isinstance(x,int)]))
```

Here is an example on how to fit the max part in the recursive function (hint: without using the actual `max()` function but by calculating the max recursively too)

```
assigned = [['A',[4, 5, 6]],['B',[7, 8, 9]],['D',[2,3]],['C',[14]]]

def recursive_max(a, best=None):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        for i in a:
            best = recursive_max(i, best)
        return best
    else:
        return best if not isinstance(a, int) else (a if best is None or a > best else best)

print(recursive_max(assigned))
```

> 14

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to simplify and combine your steps. Also, since it appears that your integer lists are always the second item in each sublist you can avoid the type checking as well.

```
from itertools import chain

assigned = [['A',[4, 5, 6]],['B',[7, 8, 9]],['D',[2,3]],['C',[14]]]

m = max(chain.from_iterable(a[1] for a in assigned))
print(m)
# 14
```

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired from [Flattening a multilevel list of lists to a single level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983117/flattening-a-multilevel-list-of-lists-to-a-single-level) and should work with any number of nested levels and most iterable types.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(lst):
    for el in lst:
      # Strings a considered values not iterables here
      if isinstance(el, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
        # Go deep
        yield from flatten(el)
      else:
        # Non iterable, non int values are discarded
        if not isinstance(el, int):
          continue
        # Int value to consider for max lookup
        yield el

l = [
  ['A', [4, 5, 6]],
  ['B', {7, 8, 90}],
  ['C', (2, 3)],
  ['D', {14: True}],
  ['E',
    [10, [0, 1, 100]],
  ]
]

m = max(flatten(l))

print(m)
```

Running exemple here: https://repl.it/@GuillaumeDeslandes/multi-level-flatten